# How would I make a Base64 encoder/decoder Powershell script?

Tags: powershell

I would like to make a base64 encoder/decoder Powershell script. I haven't done much with Powershell scripting wise, but I think im up to the task.
Things I want to do:
Switches to allow the user to specify wether to decode (-d), encode (-e), take data from a file (-f), or pipe to a file (-p).
Any help is apreciated,
James

Tried looking for CLI programs to do this, with no luck.

I now have the skeleton code for the script:

```
$Text = 'text'
$Bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($Text)
$EncodedText = [Convert]::ToBase64String($Bytes)
$EncodedText
```

I now have decode, but it doesn't work:

```
#Base64 Decode
$DecodedText = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetString([System.Convert]::FromBase64String($Text))
$DecodedText
```

Comment: What PowerShell code have you tried so far?

Comment: I used this as the basic skeleton of the script:
$Text = 'text'
$Bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($Text)
$EncodedText = [Convert]::ToBase64String($Bytes)
$EncodedText
Now I need to know how to take this, and make it so users can plug in the data to be encoded, and also the decode part and switches i mentioned.

Comment: Please update your question including the comment and code there

Comment: The error in the code above, incorrect variable name, was trapped in Discord. In the decode, `$Text` should be `$EncodedText`. Should likely be updated in the question above.

Answer (score 0):

Best practice is to use dedicated functions/features...

```
function ConvertTo-Base64 {

    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter()]
        [string]
        $String
    )

    $Bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($String)
    [Convert]::ToBase64String($Bytes)
}

function ConvertFrom-Base64 {

    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter()]
        [string]
        $Base64
    )

    $Decode = [System.Convert]::FromBase64String($Base64)
    [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString($Decode)
}
```